# How to write a trigger in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, triggers

I´ve four tables.

- User
- Service
- UsedServices
- Permission

If I assign a user to a service (saved in UsedServices), I want to check with a trigger if the user have the permission (lookup in table permission if user exists) to use the service.

In SQL it´s easy to write a trigger for that, but I don´t have any clue how to realize that in MS Access.

---

## UPDATE:

> UsedServices fields: ID | SERVICE
>
> Permission fields: ID | SERVICE | FROM | UNTIL

If a person add a record in table 'UsedServices', then i want to check if the id is in table 'Permission' ans if the Permission is still valid from now.

Comment: Until Access 2010, there are no triggers, and even with 2010 I find it easier to do things like this in code. On whatever form you're using to add a user to a service, just add a check for permission before you save the record.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200

Comment: Sorry, but Id don´t get it. I created a Formular to assign a User to a service. It´s like USER B uses INTERNET. Now I want to check if USER B have the permission in the 'Permission' table for service INTERNET and if it´s still valid. If not, than the transaction failed. In table permission there are the fields: USER | SERVICE | FROM | UNTIL

Answer (score 1):

To check if USER B have the permission in the 'Permission' table, use the BeforeUpdate event of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Cancel = YourPermissionDeniedCheckFunction(Me!UserID.Value)

    If Cancel = True Then
        MsgBox "User " & Me!UserName.Value & " has not been granted the required permissions for this task."
    End If

End Sub
```